# catching http requests in sdk from outside universal app

Tags: sdk, httprequest, win-universal-app

i'm currently working on writing a SDK that should monitor some parameters of  universal apps, one of them is catching http requests.
The code in this SDK should catch http requests that come out of the universal app which i don't have an access to the code because it can be any universal app. 
Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want something like http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore ?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as far as i'm concerned i see that this is a built in program and  i need a class to use in my runtime component to somehow catch http requests from outside my sdk which will work for any universal app that uses it, any other ideas?